# Strange logic behavior in ASP MVC view when adding and subtracting negative decimals

Tags: asp.net-mvc, math

So I've got a strange behavior happening in my ASP MVC View logic. I know it's not the best practice to have logic in a view, but that surely couldn't be causing this anyways?

I've got a foreach loop that loops through a collection, displaying the total cost, the original value, and the amount saved. But with the following code, the VALUE variable is wrong, but the Total and Price Adjusted are right.

```
@foreach (var option in Model.ProductAttributes.Single().Values)
{
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-5 columns">
      <h3>@option.Name</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="small-2 columns text-center costCol">
      <h3><strong>@{ var total = (option.Cost + option.PriceAdjustmentValue).ToString("C");}@total</strong></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="small-2 columns text-center savingsCol">
      <ul>
        <li>Value @{ var value = (option.Cost - option.PriceAdjustmentValue).ToString("C");}@value</li>
        <li>Savings @option.PriceAdjustment</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="small-3 columns text-center">
      <a href="#" class="button">Buy</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  if (!option.Equals(last)) { 
    <hr class="noTopMarginHr" />
  }
}
```

So I've debugged what is happening, and for some reason, in the value line, option.Cost is being added by option.PriceAdjustment and THEN minused. So for instance, if my cost was 80, and my PriceAdjusted was -40, then the Value would come up as 160$, and not 120$.

If I change the value line to:

```
<li>Value @{ var value = ((option.Cost + option.PriceAdjustmentValue) - option.PriceAdjustmentValue).ToString("C");}@value</li>
```

Then it works fine, but this just seems so wrong.

What is going on here? What am I missing?

Comment: What your claiming does not make sense - no combination of adding 80 and 40 can equate to 160. (it will be 120, or 40 depending on whether your adding or subtracting). And what is `PriceAdjustmentValue` vs `PriceAdjustment`. And you last line of code will always return 80

Comment: PriceAdjustmentValue is a negative decimal. PriceAdjustment is just the same decimal but converted to a string (it's not any part of the problem).

What is happening is it's taking the 80, adding 40, and then adding 40 again. But the first code snippet doesn't show that. 80 subtract -40 should be 120, not 160.

Comment: There is nothing in your code to suggest its adding 40 again.

Comment: Yeah.. I wouldn't have posted to StackOverflow if I wasn't totally confused. Believe me, I know this should be a very basic solution. Figured someone may have an idea. When I hit the line in the debugger, option.Cost has already been added to.

Comment: Are you sure `var total = (option.Cost + option.PriceAdjustmentValue)` is correct and its not `option.Cost += option.PriceAdjustmentValue`?

Comment: Yep, copy and pasted that line exactly how it is. That was my first inclination, that somehow that total line was adding to option.Cost, but I even commented it out and the problem persists.